# Jenkins stash is not stashing all files and folders

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkinsfile, Im trying to stash BuildApp
and unstash it into other docker container to run npm test.
but seems like it's missing node_modules, so npm test fails.

```
steps {
    dir("/var/jenkins_home") {
      unstash "app"
    }
    echo "Building app (CLOUD_ENV = ${env.CLOUD_ENV})"
    sh 'yarn install'
    stash name: "BuildApp", includes: "*"
    sh "ls -la ${pwd()}"
  }
```

That's where I'm trying to stash and I did debug with "ls -la ${pwd()}"
and I see that node_modules are there
but when unstash them

```
steps {
    dir("/var/jenkins_home") {
      unstash "BuildApp"
    }
    echo "Testing app (CLOUD_ENV = ${env.CLOUD_ENV})"
    // unstash 'builtApp'
    sh "ls -la ${pwd()}"
    sh 'npm test > test.out'
    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'test.out', fingerprint: true
    stash name: "testApp", includes: "*"
  }
```

I did "ls -la ${pwd()}" and I can see that node_modules folder is not there.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you `unstashing` in `dir("/var/jenkins_home")`? That might be an issue for `stash` does not only save files but also their paths AFAIK. Could you try to remove the `dir`?

Comment: Thank you.. it worked. removing dir and '**'

Comment: don't hesitate to mark my answer as the solution 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess that `*` only includes files in the current directory. In that case `**` should do the trick since it also matches path separators.

Also in your code you `unstash` in a different directory than you execute `ls`. I don't see any reason for the `dir` command, so I suggest to remove it.